# How to make separate kivy file for the following python code

Tags: python, slider, kivy

I am having below python code which will save the slider value in to the text file. Actually my intention is to get the value from kivy file and have to save it in the text-file. But unfortunately i am not getting exactly how to do it.

Separate file for kivy from that value must be sent to python file.
In python file those values have to saved.

Below is the link of code for the python.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VPTcXyWU1w9LbKypZ95Db3PkhDwvqDSNp6iUE19WWFo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: so  you want to access the current value of the Slider inside your python file?

Comment: @Dipanshu Juneja Yes Exactly and want to save the value for further use

Comment: Check out the answer. Once you have the slider's value, you can save it in a Text file if you want by opening a file. You can do a google search on how to open a file and write to it in python. Only a couple lines code

Answer (score 1):

You can access the value of Slider pretty much like how you would access the property of any other object. By doing

```
myslider = Slider(min=0,max=100,value=50)
myslider.value
```

Here is an example of a BoxLayout having a Button and a Slider. Click on the button would print the current value of the Slider

```
class MyWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.myslider = Slider(min=-100, max=100, value=25)
        self.add_widget(self.myslider)  # Add the slider
        self.mybutton = Button(text='Click to get slider val')
        self.add_widget(self.mybutton)  # Add button
        self.mybutton.bind(on_press=self.onclickgetval) # bind button to print slider value

    def onclickgetval(self,instance):
        print(self.myslider.value)


class MyRandomApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                      
    MyRandomApp().run()
```

[image]

**Please Note**
While writing everything in Python works, it can look a little messy, which is why you should make extensive use of .kv file. Its extremely easy, much more intuitive and understandable.

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept the answer if that serves your purpose.

Comment: But i am searching to get value from slider which defined inside kv file not in the same  python file. The slider is defined inside the python file. But if you define a slider inside kivy file, From that you have to get the current value and to print.

Comment: Your code had the Slider inside the Python file. Its very unclear what you were asking. If you have a Slider inside kv file, just give it an id and declare it at the top of your root in kv file by doing `myslider:myslider` and now you can access `self.myslider` inside python file.